# How to remove trigger character on autocomplete in tinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

How to remove trigger character on autocomplete in tinyMCE? Let's assume that the trigger character is `@`.
Once I select an autocomplete item, I wish to remove the preceding `@` character.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of using the autocompleter and not including the trigger character:

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/u7haab/12

The `fetch` function determines what is returned:

```
fetch: function (pattern) {
        return new tinymce.util.Promise(function (resolve) {
          var results = getMatchedNames(pattern).map(function (char) {
            return {
              type: 'autocompleteitem',
              value: char.value,     //This VALUE is what is inserted into the content via the onAction method
              text: char.value,
            }
          });
          resolve(results);
        });
}
```

...and the `onAction` method takes the value and inserts it into the editor:

```
var onAction = function (autocompleteApi, rng, value) { 
      editor.selection.setRng(rng);
      editor.insertContent(value);
      autocompleteApi.hide();
    };
```

Unless you explicitly choose to include the trigger character it won't be included if you follow this pattern.

Comment: Can we also ignore the trigger character altogether somehow? Like if I have an autocomplete list like ["apple","bananas"], then if I type character b, "bananas" autocomplete option should popup, and likewise for "apple" with character a?

Comment: To answer your follow up question - no.  The autocompleter requires a trigger character.

Comment: Receiving error: ``` Argument of type '{ type: string; value: string; text: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AutocompleterContents[] | PromiseLike<AutocompleterContents[]>'.``` on resolve(results) line.

Comment: I get no such error running the Fiddle - what browser are you using when you run the fiddle I provided?

Comment: I'm using angular and this error is a compile time error